# Meaning of の in 「現金の受け取り役」

Tags: particle-の

As mentioned, what is the actual meaning of の in 現金の受け取り役? I found the expression in a recent news article and have been wondering about its meaning.

The full sentence is

> 少年は現金**の**受け取り役とみられ、「指示に従い、受け取りにいったのは事実です」と供述しているという。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this の is used in indicating an objective. 現金の受け取り means "receiving money". For example, 本の配達(delivering books)、食事の支度(preparing foods).

格助詞1シ　http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171157/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE/

Answer (score 0):

現金の受け取り役 means "receiver of money". It stands for relationship of possession. ("Receiver for money" or something might be more natural sounding English, I'm not sure.)